# Determining Statistically Significant Differences in Views per Day of Week?

Tags: statistics, probability

I have some views per day of week data.  It's something like:

Mondays: 100k views

Tuesday: 110k views

Wednesday: 140k views

...

Sunday: 80k views

So naively, it seems like Wednesday is a better day for website traffic.  However, I also understand that it's possible these differences are attributable to variance (maybe each day has an equal probability of getting a given viewer).

How would I determine that Wednesday (for instance) is a better day for website traffic in a statistically significant fashion?

Happy to clarify if this question is unclear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a sample of the views data per day, that is:

```
views in Mondays: 120, 111, 90, 150, ..
views in Tuesdays: 50, 50, 57, 21, ..
...
views in Sundays: 201, 184, 126, 191, ..
```

These are [random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable). Let's refer to them as $V_d$, where $d$ is the week day, e.g. $V_{monday}$.

With those data, one option is to perform a [hypothesis test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).

Depending on the distribution of $V_d$, you may do different things. If they are normal (which can be also tested by means of a hypothesis test) (so that $V_d \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_d, \sigma_d)$), you can compare the means of two days, having a [null hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis) $H_0: \mu_{wednesday}  = \mu_{sunday}$ and the alternative hypothesis $H_1: \mu_{wednesday}  > \mu_{sunday}$ and choose an appropriate two sample test (depending on the variances of the distributions, sample size, etc).

If your distributions are not gaussian, you may use a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) or a [Mann-Whitney U test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test). To know how to choose between them, you can check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127027/kolmogorov-smirnov-vs-mann-whitney-u-when-there-are-ties).